# Failed to resolve entry for package "data-generator-retail"

Tags: typescript, react-admin

I have cloned this (https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin) project and tried to run it. I run command of yarn install. Still it generates this below mentioned error.
Failed to resolve entry for package "data-generator-retail". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.

I explicitly run "yarn add data-generator-retail" but still it remained same.

Comment: Which version of yarn are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, just build first using
`yarn run build`
in the root of project react-admin before running the demo. Hope this helps.